# In Samuel 19, is it Naioth or hut of prophets?

Tags: word-study, textual-criticism, 1-samuel, word-choice

In 1 Samuel 19:18 (NASB)

> So David fled and escaped, and came to Samuel at Ramah; and he informed him of everything that Saul had done to him. And he and Samuel went and stayed in **Naioth**

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naioth) quoting [McClintock and Strong](https://www.biblicalcyclopedia.com/N/naioth.html)

> from an early date [Naioth] has been interpreted to mean the huts or dwellings of a school or college of prophets over which Samuel presided.

Which is the most correct "Naioth" or "hut/tent (convent) of prophets"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

נָוִית (Naioth) only occurs six times in the OT and all in a few verses in the passage, 1 Sam 19:18 - 20:1.

BDB gives the following entry:

> **proper name, of a location in Ramah** (possibly = habitations, but dubious, see Dr 1 Samuel 19:18 HPS); — adode of prophets 1 Samuel
> 19:18,19,22,23 (twice in verse) and 1 Samuel 20:1 (where Baer נוות
> Kt); followed by בָּרָמָה (except 1 Samuel 19:18); ᵐ5 Ἀυαθ (ν dropped
> out after ἐν), so ᵐ5L A Ναυιωθ.

The fact that a group of prophets came out of Naioth and was closely associated with it strongly suggests that the founder of the "Schools of the Prophets", Samuel as its leader, and was near Ramah, Samuel's home base, argues for this as the location for the so-called "schools of the prophets".

Whether Naioth" means dwellings or similar is highly debated.